# How to move transaction code inside another function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to rewrite my firebase-functions using transactions. The question I now come upon is, should I return a Promise of Transcations? For example, I want to use a function which has a transcation parameter. But this function should not instantly perform the transaction, but instead return the Promise of it.

Here is my current function:

```
export const dbUserDocsOnCreated = functions
    .region(constants.region)
    .firestore
    .document("users/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => doOnCreatedUserDocs(db, stripe, snapshot, context));


export async function doOnCreatedUserDocs(
    db: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore, 
    stripe: Stripe, 
    snapshot: functions.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot, 
    context: functions.EventContext
) {
    try {
        const transactionPromise = db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
            const snapshotData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData = (await t.get(snapshot.ref)).data() as FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData
            
            // IF onCreate() has already been called once.
            if (!isDataNullOrEmpty(snapshotData.eventID)) {
                return Promise.all([null])
            }

            const createdUserNr: string = await getIdTransactionally(t, db, constants.collectionUsers)
            const createdStripeUser: Stripe.Response<Stripe.Customer> = await createStripeUser(stripe, snapshotData, firebaseUserEmail, currentUserNr, snapshot.id, idempotencyKey)
            
            const updateUserNrPromise: Promise<FirebaseFirestore.Transaction> = incrementIdTransactionally(t, db,  constants.collectionUsers)
            const updateUserDocsPromise: Promise<FirebaseFirestore.Transaction> = updateUserDocsTransactionally(t, snapshot.ref, createdUserNr, idempotencyKey)

            return Promise.all([
                updateUserDocsPromise,
                updateUserNrPromise,
            ])
        })

        return Promise.all([
            transactionPromise
        ])
    } catch (err) {
        // CATCHING
    }
}
```

### Used Functions that work with transactions

```
export async function incrementIdTransactionally(
    transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction, 
    db: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore, 
    doc: string
): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.Transaction> {
    const incrementor: FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue = FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
    const collectionReference: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData> = db.collection(constants.collectionAutoIds).doc(doc)

    return transaction.update(collectionReference, { id: incrementor })
}

async function updateUserDocsTransactionally(
    transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction, 
    ref: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference, 
    generatedUserNr: String,
    eventId: string,
): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.Transaction> {
    return transaction.set(ref, { 
        userNr: generatedUserNr, 
        eventId: eventId,
        optionalAddress: FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.delete() 
    }, { merge: true })
}

function createStripeUser(
    stripe: Stripe, 
    data: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData, 
    eMail: string, 
    usernr: string, 
    uid: string,
    idempotencKey: string,
): Promise<Stripe.Response<Stripe.Customer>> {
    return stripe.customers.create({
        name: data.fullName,
        email: eMail,
        description: "Created by Firebase Cloud-Functions",
        metadata: { uuid: uid, userNr: usernr },
        preferred_locales: ["de-DE"],
    }, { idempotencyKey: idempotencKey })
}
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to perform multiple operations within a single transaction based on the helper functions you are calling from inside the main function you are running. Have you checked if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749808) which goes into how to perform multiple operations helps? If not, how does it differ from what you are trying to implement?

Comment: @ErnestoContrerasPinon The question you provided is what I was looking for. The only thing what my question differs from is, how I can move the transaction operations inside another function. For example, in the question you provided, how can one move `t.set(userDoc, { "userId" : userId })` into another function. Should this function then return a promise??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749808/) and the SDK reference, it looks like the `set()`, `update()`, and `delete()` [operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Transaction) of transactions do not return promises, but they just return the same `Transaction` instance to be used in transaction chaining:

> Returns Transaction: This Transaction instance. Used for chaining method calls.

This is not the same for the `get()` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get), which does return a `Promise<DocumentSnapshot>`. I tested a simple transaction broken up into two functions, and found no apparent issues:

```js
function fireTransaction(){
    return fireDB.runTransaction((tr) => {
        const myDoc = fireDB.collection("users").doc("testUser1");
        return tr.get(myDoc).then(tDoc => {
            setUserAgeTR(tr, tDoc.ref)
        })
    })
    .then(res => console.log("Completed"))
    .catch(err => console.log("Failed Transaction: ", err))
}

function setUserAgeTR(tr, docRef){
    return tr.update(docRef, {userAge: 9999}) //Requires DocumentReference, can be obtained from 'ref'
}
```

Since you are using TypeScript, the return type for your helper functions should be `Transaction`, according to the SDK doc.

Comment: Calling `setUserAgeTR` would result in a instant update write, correct? Is it possible to delay this? Just like promises?

Comment: Every operation is still taking place inside the `runTransaction()` method, which is a promise according to the SDK [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Firestore#runtransaction). It would work exactly as described in the [general documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions), as the complete code is still a single transaction that has to either commit or fail. I suggest checking that page out for more information about this.